# Difference between `istream::get` and `operator>>(istream&, char&)`

Tags: c++, data-structures

What is the difference between using `istream::get` and `operator>>(istream&, char&)`:

```
char ch;    
cin.get(ch);
cin>>ch;
```

Can you explain the possible reason **block 1** is invalid while **block 2** is valid

```
cin.get().get();//Error **block 1**
char ch;
cin.get(ch).get(ch);//Doesn't gives an error  **block 2**
```

My guess would be:

block 1 is equivalent to `cin>> >>;` while block 2 `cin>>ch>>ch;`

Comment: Don't guess, find an introduction to programming to read. I suggest Bruce Eckel's "Thinking in C++".

Comment: Is C++ class offer some different modality to input some data. You can use operator override operator>>(std::istream &, T &) or some static method. Using >> operator is more versatile in the sense that is not limited in some data type.

Answer (score 2):

`istream::get(char c)` returns an `istream&`, while the other no-argument version returns int.

So in the second version you invoke `.get(ch)` over an `istream&` which is perfectly legal, while in the first one you attempt to call method get of an int which is **not legal**.

Answer (score 1):

**>>** is known as **extraction operator** and can be used when you want the input to be stored in some variable for example. For details please refer this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/).

When you use **.**, it means that you want to access the method of a class object.

Your first block is incorrect, bec **cin.get()** returns **int** type which doesn't have method **get()** associated to it. Where as cin,get(ch) returns value of type **istream&**.