# Difference between istream::get(char&) and operator>> (char&)

Tags: c++, istream

My question seems to be the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435818/difference-between-istreamget-and-operatoristream-char), but I didn't find an answer since the original question seems to ask something more specific.
In C++98, what is the difference between

```
char c;
cin.get(c);
```

and

```
char c;
cin >> c;
```

?

I've checked the cplusplus reference for [get](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) and [operator>>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/), and they look the same to me.

I've tried above code and they seem to behave the same when I input a char.

Comment: There is indeed an overload of [`operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) which takes only a single character.

Comment: The thing is, it's a [non-member overload](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator-free/)

Comment: @HaochenWu Not really, both return a reference to the stream.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You are right, I'm an idiot. I was trying to answer the question it pointed to.

Comment: @HaochenWu I wrongly upvoted your comment as I was sure it would return an `int` but it's the overload with no parameter which does this ...

Comment: @Unda as you seem to notice, I wasn't aware of that kind of overload. It's not trivial to a newb like me. I'm editing the question to reflect your comment.

Comment: @DiegoAlfonso Well on the link you provided, it's written after the description of each member-function operator 'See [operator>>](http://www.cplusplus.com/istream:operator%3E%3E) for additional overloads (as non-member functions) of this operator'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference depends on when there is a whitespace character on the stream buffer.

Consider the input ' foo'

```
char c;
cin.get(c);
```

Will store `' '` in c

However

```
char c;
cin >> c;
```

Will skip the whitespace and store `'f'` in c

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what's already been said, `std::istream::get()` is also an unformatted input function so the [`gcount()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) of the stream is affected, unlike the formatted extractor. Most of the overloads of `get()` and [`getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) have mostly been made obselete by the introduction of `std::string`, its stream extractors, and [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). I'd say to use `std::istream::get()` whenever you need a single, unformatted character straight from the buffer (by using its single or zero argument overload). It's certainly quicker than turning off the skipping of whitespace first before using the formatted extractor. Also use `std::string` instead of raw character buffers and [`is >> str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) for formatted data or `std::getline(is, str)` for unformatted data.